# Shader turns white in Game view in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, models

I am working on endless runner type of game. I am facing a weird problem of shader. I can see my object perfect in Scene view, but in Game view they are white. Please check the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to change shader? Which platform you are using?

Comment: If this is **not** a standard shader then no one can really help you until you post the shader code.

Comment: Fog can also cause this, as you've got environment disabled in the scene view. I.e. everything else is unaffected by fog, except for your vehicle's shader.

Comment: maybe the lighting issues. turn of your lights in scene then check

Comment: I have tried to turn off lights as well, but no effect @MohammadFaizanKhan

Comment: It is happening with standard shader as well @Programmer

Comment: @maximelian1986 I tried to use all the native shaders, I am using Unity 5.5

Comment: First of all, the Game looks beautiful. Congrats if you made that. Secondly, I really can't think of any other likely problem that is causing this. Can you make a copy of your project, remove all your important scripts and models but leave the car that is turning into white in the scene. Now, check and make sure that the problem is still there. Upload this project to somewhere and provide a link here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you so much. Yes we are making it, I got the solution. Stupid me, I have enabled the Fog.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Thanks :). It worked.

Comment: You are welcome. You can post your solution as answer. That will definitely  help some people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the fog from lighting section solved the problem. Thanks @LukeBriggs and @Programmer.